# For each to extract files from different subfolders

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I need to load files from different subfolders in Azure Blob Storage to Azure SQL using For each activity but it does not working. Is There a way to read from different subfolders?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- You can use `Get metadata` activity to get the names of all the folders and then iterate through these folder names (build path inside for each), considering all the sub folders are at same hierarchy level.
- The following is the output of my `Get metadata` activity (child items of the folder containing sub-directories):

[image]

- Now inside for each loop, you can use the current item value in your path and copy the data as required. I have used set variable activity for demonstration using the dynamic content `data/ip/@{item().name}`. @item().name would contain the name of sub directory for each iteration.

[image]

- Here, `data` is container name, `ip` is parent directory and `01` is sub-directory name.